# Psychopy does not quit at end of script when using sounds

Tags: python, audio, psychopy, pyo

I've encountered an odd bug using psychopy recently, where my script does not kill psychopy when it is terminating.

This only happens when I add a sound to my routine and when I make psychopy generate a sound or play a sound from a file. In other words, just loading `sound` from psychopy does not result in my script being unable to quit. Only when I make a call to a sound as in `s=sound.Sound(value="C", secs=0.15)`, and even if that sound ins't actually played in my routine by `s.play()`

I've tried googling to see if other people reported this issue but it seems I'm kinda lonely. I've tested it on two Macs specs below:

MacBook Pro runs:

- OSX Yosemite
- enthought python 2.7
- latest psychopy (recently installed with `easy_install`)
- pyglet 1.2
- pyo 0.7.5
- Intel Iris graphics card/built in

iMac runs:

- everything similar to above
- NVIDIA separate graphics card (don't remember model right now)

Here is some example code I am running. Does this quit fine for you?
Does anyone have suggestions regarding what might be going on?
Let me know if more info is needed about my system etc.

```
#Display a text together with a sound synced
#to the onset of the visual display
#---------------------------------------------
from psychopy import core, visual,sound
win = visual.Window([800,800], color='gray', allowGUI=False, winType='pyglet', monitor='testMonitor',units='pix')

stim = visual.TextStim(win, text="Hi!")
s=sound.Sound(value="C", secs=0.15)

startText=visual.TextStim(win, text="starting")
startText.draw()
win.flip()
core.wait(1)
for i in xrange(2):

    for frameN in range(70): 
        stim.draw()
        if frameN == 0:      
            win.flip()
            s.play()
        else:
            win.flip()         
    win.flip()
  core.wait(.2)
```

Thanks :)

Comment: +1 for a reproducible example (but indentation on last line needs a fix: not sure what level it should be at though). Runs fine for me otherwise (Mac OS X 10.10.3, MacBook Air, PsychoPy standalone 1.82.01). Have you tried changing the order of the sound libraries in PsychoPy's preferences? Using `pyo` instead of `pygame` can sometimes fix sound issues.

Comment: Yep I tried that. Pyo is the default. Haven't tried to run in standalone psychopy though since I haven't installed it. Strange...

Comment: What if you explicitly call `core.quit()`?

Comment: I did add that yes. It seems to be a problem with pyo not being able to close. But that's all I was able to make out.

Comment: I came upon this post after googling around for the same exact problem, although since this is my first PsychoPy program I didn't know that the issue was with sound.  Running your code produces the same problematic behavior -- fails to terminate about half the time (sometimes even crashes!) using 2015 MacBook pro, PsychPy standalone 1.84.2, MacOS Sierra.  Would love an update if you've figured it out...